# Powershell.Create returns null on debugging

Tags: c#, powershell

On running my below code, I get error on Powershell.create as below, has anyone seen this error before, I have Micosoft.Powershell.Sdk installled. What is wrong?? also I dont have InvokeAsync method in my powershell methods? why is that

Code:

```
public async Task<string> RunScript( string contentScript, Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> parameters)
        {
            List<string> parameterList = new List<string>();
            foreach( var item in parameters )
            {
                parameterList.Add( item.Value.ToString() );
            }
            using( PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create() )
            {
                ps.AddScript( contentScript );
                ps.AddParameters( parameters );
                
                IAsyncResult async = ps.BeginInvoke();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach( PSObject result in ps.EndInvoke( async ) )
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine( result.ToString() );
                }
                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Error:

*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
5__4 was null.*

Comment: Which version of .NET and which version of the SDk?

Comment: I see this when i click F12 on my PowerShell key word  Assembly System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// C:\Users\Test\.nuget\packages\powershellstandard.library\5.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Management.Automation.dll
#endregion

Comment: Also Microsft Sdk version is 7.1.0 and I tried with latest one as well

Comment: If I make the method synchronous that is remove Task<string> with string I just get error as Object reference Not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by installing Microsoft.PowerShell.Sdk(7.0.0) and Microsft.WSMan.Runtime(7.0.0) version